# How to render data from state in React table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm currently using React Table to build a table to input my data. Data is being pushed through from the server and is being updated on the state. 
The state "Names" is an array of hashes with 2 keys, number and name.

However, the table is not updating with any data.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
class Table extends Component {
  state = {
    names: []
  };

  connectSocket = () => {
    const socketURL = 'http://localhost:3001/';
    const socket = io(socketURL);
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connected socket server');
    });
    socket.io.on('connect_error', () => {
      console.log('Error connecting to server');
    });
    socket.on('updates', (data) => {
      this.setState(
        {
          names: data
        },
        () => {
          // console.log(this.state.names);
        }
      );
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.connectSocket();
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: 'ID',
        accesor: 'number',
        sortable: false
      },
      {
        Header: 'Number',
        accesor: 'number',
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        accesor: 'name',
        sortable: false
      }
    ];
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          columns={columns}
          data={this.state.names}
          noDataText={'Loading...'}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the console printing ?

Comment: console is printing [{number:0, name:'String'}] and array would keep incrementing as its adding new hashes

Comment: your problem is with the initial data, or with subsequent updates?

Comment: and does your socket send the updates only or the full data with each change ?

Comment: problem is with initial data. the socket sends data at each 1s internval

Comment: so no data is ever shown  ?

Comment: correct, doesn't load initially

Comment: this is quite strange, can you try consoling the state in your render method ?

Answer (score 0):

mistyped columns definition. Change accesor to accessor